# Find specific values and trancate

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find group values?

Example I have following SKU's:

```
SkuId                   Description

VN0A46ZERWV113000M      CLASSIC
VN0A46ZERWV112000M      CLASSIC
VN0A46ZERWV111500M      CLASSIC
VN0A3WCVAZ31XXL         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ310XL         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ3100S         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ3100M         Modern
VN0A3TE3RCO113000M      Not Classic
VN0A3TE3RCO112000M      Not Classic
VN0A3TE3RCO111500M      Not Classic
```

How to describe...:) So, I need find all Sku's with the same description, find the same part in SKU, and add new row after every group. In general, the same part is first 12 characters.

Example in Result:

```
SkuId                   Description

VN0A46ZERWV113000M      CLASSIC
VN0A46ZERWV112000M      CLASSIC
VN0A46ZERWV111500M      CLASSIC
VN0A46ZERWV1            NEW
VN0A3WCVAZ31XXL         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ310XL         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ3100S         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ3100M         Modern
VN0A3WCVAZ31            NEW
VN0A3TE3RCO113000M      Not Classic
VN0A3TE3RCO112000M      Not Classic
VN0A3TE3RCO111500M      Not Classic
VN0A3TE3RCO1            NEW
```

Comment: What is the logic by which `VN0A46ZERWV1` comes out as the SKU from e.g. `VN0A46ZERWV111500M` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we should truncate first 12 characters in SkuId and add this characters like separate Sku

Comment: You mention something about this row "after" but there is nothing in this data that represents order. And are you trying to do this in a select statement or add data to the table. This question needs a LOT of help to become clear.

Comment: Your looking for the function [LEFT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_left.asp)  edit: Linked vba left instead of sql

Comment: INSERT YourTable (SkuId, Description) SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(SkuId, 12), 'NEW' FROM YourTable

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you can try to use `UNION ALL` and [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to make it.

use `substring` to get the first 12 characters from `SkuId` column in subquery then `distinct` remove duplicate first 12 characters `SkuId` then `UNION ALL` two result set.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  SkuId VARCHAR(100),
  Description VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A46ZERWV113000M' ,'CLASSIC');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A46ZERWV112000M' ,'CLASSIC');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A46ZERWV111500M' ,'CLASSIC');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3WCVAZ31XXL' ,'Modern');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3WCVAZ310XL' ,'Modern');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3WCVAZ3100S' ,'Modern');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3WCVAZ3100M' ,'Modern');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3TE3RCO113000M' ,'Not Classic');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3TE3RCO112000M' ,'Not Classic');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('VN0A3TE3RCO111500M' ,'Not Classic');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  select SkuId,Description
  from T
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT distinct substring(SkuId,1,12) ,'New'  
  FROM T
) t1
order by SkuId desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95d5d40/6/0)**:

```
|              SkuId | Description |
|--------------------|-------------|
| VN0A46ZERWV113000M |     CLASSIC |
| VN0A46ZERWV112000M |     CLASSIC |
| VN0A46ZERWV111500M |     CLASSIC |
|       VN0A46ZERWV1 |         New |
|    VN0A3WCVAZ31XXL |      Modern |
|    VN0A3WCVAZ310XL |      Modern |
|    VN0A3WCVAZ3100S |      Modern |
|    VN0A3WCVAZ3100M |      Modern |
|       VN0A3WCVAZ31 |         New |
| VN0A3TE3RCO113000M | Not Classic |
| VN0A3TE3RCO112000M | Not Classic |
| VN0A3TE3RCO111500M | Not Classic |
|       VN0A3TE3RCO1 |         New |
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @KirillRodeonov You should really ACCEPT answers, especially when they supply an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the additional rows you want are:

```
select skuid, 'NEW'
from (select distinct left(skuid, 12) as skuid, description
      from skus
     ) t;
```

For your data and probably for your problem, this will probably do:

```
select distinct left(skuid, 12) as skuid, 'New'
from skus;
```

If you specifically want to exclude "names" that have different descriptions:

```
select left(skuid, 12) as skuid, 'New'
from skus
group by left(skuid, 12)
having min(description) = max(description);
```

You can add these into the table using `insert`:

```
insert into skus (skuid, description)
    select distinct left(skuid, 12) as skuid, 'New'
    from skus;
```

If you just want a result set, then use `union` and the correct `order by`:

```
select skuid, description
from ((select skuid, description, 1 as priority
       from skus
      ) union all
      (select distinct left(skuid, 12) as skuid, 'New', 2
       from skus
      )
     ) sd
order by skuid, priority;
```